# Visual Studio 2008 IDE, typing open quote doesn't output it until quote is typed again

Tags: visual-studio

When I type an open quote (") in visual studio, nothing happens till I type quote again. This is most frustrating because quotes are used everywhere.

How can I get normal quote typing behavior in VS2008?

Thanks

Normal quote behavior: I would like the quotation character to immediately appear on screen when I type it, like in other applications.

Comment: Does this happen in all editors? Or just in the code editor, HTML editor etc?

Comment: What is meant by "normal quote typing behavior"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting Visual Studio fixes this bug temporarily. Luckily I restart visual studio at least once or twice a day.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your regional settings?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560073/strange-visual-studio-2008-behavior-when-pressing-keys)

Comment: thanks, that's exactly my problem, I'll test it but so far looks good.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.